# UICollectionView right height cell overlap

Tags: ios, image, uicollectionview, overlap, uicollectionviewcell

I'm new building UICollectionView and I have an issue. I would like to display images that have 300px width and calculate the right height scale. To do this, I did :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *image = [photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if(image){

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

    float scale = (image.size.height/image.size.width)*300;

    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, 300, scale )];

    [cell addSubview:imageView];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}else{

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}


return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImage *image = [photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    float scale = (image.size.height/image.size.width)*300;
    return  CGSizeMake(300, scale);
}
```

This seems to work at the beginning but as soon as I scroll down, images start to overlap each others. Is that any way to avoid this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to resize cells in UICollectionView, use UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Check out the Ray Wenderlich Tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: Isn't what I do with "- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" ?

Comment: Just specify a CGSize for your Collection View cell in return function. Example: ' CGSize *cellSize = CGSizeMake(50,50); ' 'return cellSize;'. Or change the frame of your imageView according to cell size.

Comment: Yeah but if I do want to have specific height for each cell ?

Comment: Then you have to get your image size or any other size you want to have, inside the function  '(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView )collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath"' and specify that size in return...

Comment: So, it is what I do and I have an overlaping issue when I scroll down.

Comment: Try specifying spacing betweeen the cells.